# OrientDB: Is it possible to define a vertex which is instance of multiple classes?

Tags: multiple-inheritance, orientdb

I'm experimenting with OrientDB and I would like to model a non disjunctive inheritance. For example: 
- there are Person
- a Student is a Person
- a Worker is a Person
- "Alberto" is both a Student and Worker.
Is it possible to model this situation with only the three classes I defined (Student, Worker, Person) or shall I introduce a new class WorkingStudent, extending both Worker and Student, containing "Alberto"?

I suppose a vertex cannot be instance of more than one class since the system would not know in which cluster to put it but I haven't found an explicit answer to my question, yet.

Cheers,

Alberto (the working student :-) )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you may trying to solve this the wrong way. For instance, Alberto will presumably always be a Person. But when Alberto graduates, he will no longer be a Student. In fact, he might also lose his job and no longer be a Worker. Moving him from one class to another is a considerable issue.

I'd create separate, smaller nodes of Worker and Student. Then create edges from Person to Worker, or Person to Student. The edge can be named "Is A".

Now, it is very easy to add new categories, for instance "Parent" or "Spouse", without having to worry about changing your class inheritance.

One of the fantastic advantages of a Graph database...

Comment: I see your point, @silverfox1948. Thanks. However, like that I cannot impose any constraint at the schema level, for example I would not be able to impose that a worker must have a salary. Obviously this is only an example I made up. In the real database I'm building a member of the parent class can have multiple child classes but cannot change them.

Comment: Actually, if "Worker" is a node(Vertex), then it is possible to create constraints on properties of the node. A property can have a constraint of "Mandatory" - meaning it is required, along with minimum/maximum values.

Comment: I strongly encourage you to NOT use inheritance to solve problems of categorization. Worker/Student, etc. are simply transient, non-exclusive categories. If you add another category, your inheritance requirements will explode exponentially. Just try adding one more category and see how many child classes you now have to create to allow a person to be categorized in one of the new possible combinations.

Comment: I've now understood what you meant by your first answer. Seems elegant, I'll try to implement it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

in OrientDb a vertex can be an instance of multiple class.
Use this command

```
create class WorkingStudent extends Working,Student
```

Kind regards.

Comment: Hello Alessandro, thanks for your answer. I was actually wondering if it would be possible to model a working student without creating a new class. In neo4j I would write something like: `CREATE (alberto: Student :Worker :Person {name: "alberto"})`

Comment: no, you cannot do it. In Neo4j you just have labels, while in OrientDB you have class hierarchies, polymorphism and all the rest, so you have to define class hierarchies on the database schema